# How to calculate multiple solutions from big to small with FindInstance funtion

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

**I want to find the nearest 50(or 80, even 100)solutions under 1.4628 from big to small**, I tried FindInstance function in MMA, but still cannot get the desired results I need.Here is my code:

```
Clear["Global'*"];
$RecursionLimit = Infinity;
nco = 1.4681; ncl = 1.4628; nair = 1; rco = 4.2*10^3; rcl = 
 62.5*10^3; \[CapitalDelta]n = ncl - nair;
wl = 1000;
u = 2*\[Pi]*rcl*((ncl^2 - neffcl^2)^((1/2))/wl);
w = 2*\[Pi]*rcl*((neffcl^2 - nair^2)^((1/2))/wl);
J0 = BesselJ[0, u]; J1 = BesselJ[1, u];
K0 = BesselK[0, w]; K1 = BesselK[1, w];
N[
 FindInstance[
  J1/(u*J0) == (1 - 2*\[CapitalDelta]n)*(K1/(w*K0)) && 
   1.45 < neffcl < 1.463, neffcl, PositiveReals, 50]
 ]
TM
Plot[{J1/(u*J0), (1 - 2*\[CapitalDelta]n)*(K1/(w*K0))}, {neffcl, -2, 
  2}]
Plot[{J1/(u*J0), (1 - 2*\[CapitalDelta]n)*(K1/(w*K0))}, {neffcl, 
  1.453, 1.463}, PlotRange -> {-0.005, 0.005}]
```

I plotted two pictures, the first one represent the solutions of the unsolved function, and in the 2nd one, I plotted the formula with neffcl from 1.453 to 1.463.

As for the given results, we can see that MMA only returns 15 solutions, not 50 I set, but we can see both in the first and 2nd picture that there is absolutely more than 15 solutions for my formula, here is what MMA returns:

```
{{neffcl -> 1.45092}, {neffcl -> 1.45193}, {neffcl -> 
1.45289}, {neffcl -> 1.4538}, {neffcl -> 1.45467}, {neffcl -> 
   1.45549}, {neffcl -> 1.45628}, {neffcl -> 1.45701}, {neffcl -> 
   1.45835}, {neffcl -> 1.45951}, {neffcl -> 1.4622}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46241}, {neffcl -> 1.46257}, {neffcl -> 1.46269}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46277}}
```

[image]
picture1
[image]
Picture2

Somebody can tell me what is wrong with my code and how can I make it work?
Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global'*"];

nco = 1.4681 // Rationalize; 
ncl = 1.4628 // Rationalize; 
nair = 1; 
rco = 4.2*10^3 // Rationalize; 
rcl = 62.5*10^3 // Rationalize; 
Δn = ncl - nair;
wl = 1000;
u = 2*π*rcl*((ncl^2 - neffcl^2)^((1/2))/wl);
w = 2*π*rcl*((neffcl^2 - nair^2)^((1/2))/wl);
J0 = BesselJ[0, u];
J1 = BesselJ[1, u];
K0 = BesselK[0, w]; K1 = BesselK[1, w];

eqn = J1/(u*J0) == (1 - 2*Δn)*(K1/(w*K0)) // FullSimplify;
```

To find a large number of solutions you need to widen the interval, e.g., `6/5 < neffcl < 1463/1000`

```
sol = NSolve[{eqn, 6/5 < neffcl < 1463/1000}, neffcl, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Length@sol

(* 100 *)

Plot[{J1/(u*J0), (1 - 2*Δn)*(K1/(w*K0))},
 {neffcl, 6/5, 1463/1000},
 PlotRange -> {-0.005, 0.005},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{neffcl, J1/(u*J0)}], neffcl] /. sol},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Re your comment

```
sol[[-1]]

(* {neffcl -> 1.46219836998378} *)
```

Since `NSolve` is numeric, i.e., inexact solver; there is no guarantee that all roots are found. Tightening the interval can give different results. With a tighter interval, you can switch to an exact solver (`Solve` or `Reduce`).

```
(sol2 = Solve[{eqn, 146/100 < neffcl < 1463/1000}, neffcl, 
    Method -> Reduce]) // N[#, 15] &

(* Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.

{{neffcl -> 1.46002938826877}, {neffcl -> 1.46050070411957}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46092804493494}, {neffcl -> 1.46131144933488}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46165095192033}, {neffcl -> 1.46194658328016}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46219836998378}, {neffcl -> 1.46240633453443}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46257049518216}, {neffcl -> 1.46269086505254}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46276744566539}} *)
```

Note however that the exact solver indicates that the results may not be complete. Tighten the interval until the results do not change.

```
(sol3 = Solve[{eqn, 14622/10000 < neffcl < 1463/1000}, neffcl, 
    Method -> Reduce]) // N[#, 15] &

(* Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.

{{neffcl -> 1.46240633453443}, {neffcl -> 1.46257049518216}, {neffcl -> 
   1.46269086505254}, {neffcl -> 1.46276744566539}} *)
```

While the warning is still present, the results in the common interval are identical.

```
sol3 === sol2[[-4 ;;]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience on this question, but it seems that there is still some problem that remains to be sovled. We can see that in my results I posted, the biggest neffcl value I got is 1.46277, which is very close to 1.4628. Then in your code, the biggest neffcl returned is 1.4622, there is some difference between the two numbers. I then changed the solve range of neffcl, making it 1.45->1.463, I got the same results like I posted, I don't know why would this happen, and how to chose a proper neffcl range for such a problem.